# How to increase the IntelliSense analysis size of big CSS files?

Tags: css, visual-studio, intellisense

I have a big CSS file(3.5MB) that VS 2022 doesn't seem to pick up and provide classes suggestions.

Is there any way to increase the analysis limits of IntelliSense and provide code completions?

Comment: I am having the same problem but with bootstrap, IntelliSense not working, I even updated to version 17.0.2, and still the same problem

Comment: This used to work better in VS 2019.

Comment: Can you share the CSS on Github or [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: @onkarruikar Take `tailwind-dark.css` from [here](https://unpkg.com/browse/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/)

Comment: You would have get a prompt for 1st time,it links you to settings where you can increase max word limit

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu tried to open it but VS freezes indefinetely -_-

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu nevermind, after few attempts I managed to open the file but there was no prompt as you say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that seemed to work was to close all VS windows, delete the `.vs` folder from the target project and then reopen the project and leave the background task finish before making any interaction.

Now I have all the CSS suggested, but it does still fail from time to time without knowing why, so I leave this question open if there's a way to increase IntelliSense limits

**[UPDATE]** I opened the same issue at the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/intellisense-in-vs-1702-cant-provide-css-suggestio/1609838?from=email) and it does seem to have been fixed with `VS 2022 17.1 Preview 3`, I didn't test it(I'm gonna do that when it's in the stable branch) but given no further way to fix I will mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm likely misreading this, but you might be able to try [increasing the Intellisense cache size](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-c-extension-march-2019-update/#intellisense-cache-settings). I'd also suggest attempting to [clean out the icph folder](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_what-is-the-ipch-folder) of any extra cache stored in there.

Comment: I'm talking about Visual Studio 2022, not Visual Studio Code